# How to fix "ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels" in python when I try to do?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

I do this on a dataframe with no duplicate rows or columns or indexes. But I get this error:

```
"ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels"
```

How do I fix this error? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
The dataframe is like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | [1,2,3,4] | [absd,efgh,ij``k] |
| 2 | user2 | [5,6,7,8] | [lmkf,sfajf] |
| 3 | user3 | [9] |  |

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the dataframe?

Comment: @richardec just added what the dataframe looks like

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: for example for  user 1 would have 4 rows with column "A" and "B" with 1 and user1 as values and column "C" and "D" will have one out of all the items in the lists in each one.

Comment: In your example though, the lists in `C` and `D` have different numbers of items.

Comment: That would come out as empty column value. so for user 1 column C and D will have 4 and 3 rows filled with 4th row in D would be empty

Comment: Or at least I thought that would work. But I guess not. Any other way I could do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two columns have lists of the same length, then two columns can be exploded at the same time.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1,"user1",[1,2,3,4],["absd","efgh","ij``k"]],
    [2,"user2",[5,6,7,8],["lmkf","sfajf"]],
    [3,"user3",[9],[]],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=list("ABCD")
)

def fill_list(a,length):
    _a = a.copy()
    tail = [None for i in range(length - len(a))]
    _a.extend(tail)
    return _a

df.assign(
    D = df[["C","D"]].apply(lambda x:fill_list(x[1],len(x[0])),axis=1,raw=False)
).explode(["C","D"])
```

Pandas version is 1.3.5

Solution for multiple columns

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1, "user1", [1, 2, 3, 4], ["absd", "efgh", "ij``k"], [3, 2]],
    [2, "user2", [5, 6, 7, 8], ["lmkf", "sfajf"], [3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6]],
    [3, "user3", [9], [], [3, 2]],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=list("ABCDE")
)


def fill_list(*lists):
    _lists = lists[:]
    max_len = max([len(x) for x in _lists])
    for l in _lists:
        tail = [None for i in range(max_len - len(l))]
        l.extend(tail)
    return _lists


list_cols = ["C", "D", "E"]

df[list_cols] = df[list_cols].apply(lambda x: fill_list(*x), axis=1, raw=False, result_type="expand")
df.explode(list_cols)
```

Comment: is it the same with multiple columns?

Comment: Yes, I think it will work if you make all columns have list values of the same length. And `fill_list` function will needs some changes.

Comment: Can you tell me how that fill_list would change for a random set of columns where columns, in the beginning, may not necessarily have more length than others? for example columns c,d,e where c has values with length of 2 , d with 5 and e with 3

Comment: @garaofthesand Hi, I've updated the answer to add consideration for the multiple columns case.You can try this.